# SWT Dialog of two UI Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

In one SWT Dialog, I'm going to add login and time check function.

```
public class LoginDialog extends Dialog   {

   //basic code

    /**
     * Create contents of the dialog.
     */
    private void createContents() {
        //UI code

        RealtimeThread realtimeThread=new RealtimeThread(lbl_time, btn_login);

        Thread thread=new Thread(realtimeThread);
        thread.start();
    }

    //relevance methods

    }

    class RealtimeThread implements Runnable{
    private Label lbl_time;
    private Button btn_login;

    public RealtimeThread(Label lbl_time, Button btn_login) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.lbl_time=lbl_time;
        this.btn_login=btn_login;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while(true){
                    int year, month, day, hour, min, sec;

                    year=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy").format(new Date())));
                    month=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("MM").format(new Date())));
                    day=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new Date())));
                    hour=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("HH").format(new Date())));
                    min=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("mm").format(new Date())));
                    sec=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format(new Date())));

                    lbl_time.setText(year +"year " + month +"month " + day + "day " + hour + ": " + min + ": " + sec    );
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I want to check the time in real time. And login function to work at the same time. But time runs when code is executed, but dialog capabilities is freeze.
In run()while(true) function has caused a freeze. 
How this solved?

Comment: Use Job APIs http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html

Comment: You probably want to use `Display.timerExec` to run a short piece of code repeatedly - but your current code isn't very clear.